# Django. Simple FormView not saving

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm kind of new to django generic FormView. I'm missing something obvious, the form renders correctly but it is not saving the data:

**forms.py**

```
from perfiles.models import Perfil

class FormEditarPerfil(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Perfil
        fields = ('descripcion',)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from forms import FormEditarPerfil

class EditarPerfil(FormView):
    template_name = "perfiles/editar_perfil.html"
    form_class = FormEditarPerfil

    def get_success_url(self):
        url = reverse_lazy('perfiles:propio', kwargs={'username': self.request.user.username})
        return url
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right path! But `FormView` doesn't save your model, as the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView) indicates:

> A view that displays a form. On error, redisplays the form with
>   validation errors; on success, redirects to a new URL.

You are looking for [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview). This way you don't need to create a separate form, just use the `fields` attribute in your view:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from perfiles.models import Perfil

class EditarPerfil(UpdateView):
    template_name = "perfiles/editar_perfil.html"
    model = Perfil
    fields = ['descripcion']

    def get_success_url(self):
        url = reverse_lazy('perfiles:propio', kwargs={'username': self.request.user.username})
        return url
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the view's `form_valid` method because the `FormView` class does not call `form.save()` and instead, just redirect the user to the success url.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()
    return super(EditarPerfil, self).form_valid(form)
```

Although, I would agree with @Filly's answer. If you are creating a new object, use `CreateView`, otherwise, use `UpdateView`.